# Need help with private Tor network setup

Tags: private

I'm working on my thesis, the goal of which is to create my own instance of a private Tor network. I currently have 5 nodes in my network, 1 node is a client and 4 nodes are for creating circuits(Directory Authority-DA, Guard, Relay and Exit). Yesterday I set the necessary flag(*TestingDirAuthVoteGuard*) on DA to make one of the nodes become Guard. Since then, I have the following statements in Nyx:

**DA**: Failed to find node for hop #2 of our path, No available nodes when trying to choose node. Failing.

**Guard**: Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. No available nodes when trying to choose node. Failing.

**Relay**: Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. No available nodes when trying to choose node. Failing.

**Exit**: All routers are down or won't exit -- choosing a doomed exit at random.  Failed to choose an exit server.

I would be very grateful if someone would be willing to help me/explain this to me, I can also post torrc/excerpts from Nyx. Alternatively, I'd also be happy for directions on what to study in the documentation.

Thank you.